# How do I uncollapse a margin?

Tags: css, margin

Collapsing margins in CSS: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins

I understand the [purpose of the feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1438114/for-what-reason-margin-collapse-rules-were-introduced-in-css), but I'm trying to do layout, and I can't figure out how to turn it off.

The way usually explained in CSS tutorials is to either:

1. Add a border
2. Add a padding

All of these have side effects that become obvious when you're dealing with pixel-perfect layouts with background images and fixed paddings.

Is there any way to simply disable the collapsing without having to shove extra pixels into the layout? It doesn't make any sense for me to have to visually affect the document to change behavior like this.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19718634/how-to-disable-margin-collapsing

Answer (score 28, accepted):

well you need something in between to "break" the collapsing.

my first thought was to use a div with `display:none` set in between, but that doesn't seem to work.

so I tried:

```
<div style="overflow: hidden; height: 0px; width: 0px;">.</div>
```

which seems to do the job nicely (at least in firefox, don't have internet explorer installed here to test it...)

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div style="margin: 100px;">.</div>
        <div style="overflow: hidden; height: 0px; width: 0px;">.</div>
        <div style="margin: 100px;">.</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works for me in Firefox, Chrome, Opera and IE6 on Linux. Good job, I was about to post that it was impossible...

Comment: Seems to work in IE6 as well. It's astounding that you need extra markup to acomplish this though.

Comment: Actually, close, but not quite there. The margins are still collapsing, they're just not collapsing against eachother. Consider:

  <div style="background-color: red;">
    <div style="margin: 100px;">.</div>
  </div>
  
  <div style="overflow: hidden; height: 0px; width: 0px;">.</div>
  
  <div style="background-color: blue">
    <div style="margin: 100px;">.</div>
  </div>

Comment: well, id you put the overflow:hidden div inside the background divs, it still works (though the markup is getting uglier and uglier this way...).
like <background div><overflow div/><margin div/><overflow div/></div>
there has to be a more elegant solution to this. Though, knowing how webdesign is, there probably isnt :)

Comment: Just as a point (bit of a necro I guess, but hey): you could use a non-breaking space (`&nbsp;`) rather than a period just to ensure the div will never show up.

Comment: To add to what @connec mentioned, using `&nbsp;` instead of `.` would prevent a stray period from showing up for page descriptions in search engine results (extra spaces would most likely be stripped, but not necessarily a period).

Answer (score 17):

From IE8 you could do:

```
<div class="uncollapse-margins">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
<div class="uncollapse-margins">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
```

With CSS:

```
.uncollapse-margins:before,
.uncollapse-margins:after
{
    content: "\00a0"; /* No-break space character */
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why, but this doesn't work for me.

Comment: @norsewulf Works for me. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y9VAu/4/).

Comment: @norsewulf -  It only works if there is an additional block element within the container. With the specific code above, it works because of the presence of the child p elements inside the div's. If you remove the p elements or replace them with span elements this solution is inviable. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/clarketm/y9VAu/11/)

Answer (score 12):

Use Flex or Grid layout.

In flex and grid containers, there's no such thing as margin collapsing.

More details in the specs:

> [**3. Flex Containers: the `flex` and `inline-flex` `display`
>   values**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-containers)
>
> A flex container establishes a new flex formatting context for its
>   contents. This is the same as establishing a block formatting context,
>   except that flex layout is used instead of block layout. For example,
>   floats do not intrude into the flex container, and the flex
>   container’s margins do not collapse with the margins of its contents.
>
> [**5.1. Establishing Grid Containers: the `grid` and `inline-grid`
>   display
>   values**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#grid-containers)
>
> A grid container establishes a new grid formatting context for its
>   contents. This is the same as establishing a block formatting context,
>   except that grid layout is used instead of block layout: floats do not
>   intrude into the grid container, and the grid container’s margins do
>   not collapse with the margins of its contents.

Answer (score 7):

Eric Meyer refers to your exact point in his article [Uncollapsing margins](http://complexspiral.com/publications/uncollapsing-margins/).

See the text of the article after Figure 6 for his approach. He mentions that 1px padding/border is typically the way to go, but offers a pretty simple solution for instances where there's no flexibility in adding that additional pixel.

It involves manually overriding margins on each element though, so I'm not sure if it will work for your particular case.

Answer (score 6):

One neat trick to disable margin collapsing that has no visual impact, as far as I know, is setting the padding of the parent to `0.05px`:

```
.parentClass {
    padding: 0.05px;
}
```

The padding is no longer 0 so collapsing won't occur anymore but at the same time the padding is small enough that visually it will round down to 0.

If some other padding is desired, then apply padding only to the "direction" in which margin collapsing is not desired, for example `padding-top: 0.05px;`.

**Working example:**

```css
.noCollapse {
  padding: 0.05px;
}

.parent {
  background-color: red;
  width: 150px;
}

.children {
  margin-top: 50px;

  background-color: lime;      
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<h3>Border collapsing</h3>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="children">
  </div>
</div>

<h3>No border collapsing</h3>
<div class="parent noCollapse">
  <div class="children">
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit:** changed the value from `0.1` to `0.05`. From [this small test](https://codepen.io/surdu/pen/GWMNZK), it seems that Firefox takes the `0.1px` padding into consideration. Though, `0.05px` seemes to do the trick.

Comment: The best answer I've ever seen on the subject!

Comment: 0.01px avoids collapsing in modern FF (v66).  0.001px collapses.

Comment: 0.01px collapses in Chrome, but 0.02px does not.