# How to disable margin-collapsing?

Tags: css, margin

Is there a way to disable margin-collapsing altogether?  The only solutions I've found (by the name of "uncollapsing") entail using a 1px border or 1px padding.  I find this unacceptable: the extraneous pixel complicates calculations for no good reason.  Is there a more reasonable way to disable this margin-collapsing?

Comment: Use Flex or Grid layout, where margin collapsing doesn't exist: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46496701/3597276

Comment: Simply give elements a value for `margin-bottom` but leave `margin-top` as 0.

Comment: I made a package to make the calculation easier: https://www.npmjs.com/package/collapsed-margin

Comment: https://www.joshwcomeau.com/css/rules-of-margin-collapse/

Answer (score 347, accepted):

There are two main types of margin collapse:

- Collapsing margins between adjacent elements
- Collapsing margins between parent and child elements

Using a padding or border will prevent collapse only in the latter case. Also, any value of `overflow` different from its default (`visible`) applied to the parent will prevent collapse. Thus, both `overflow: auto` and `overflow: hidden` will have the same effect. Perhaps the only difference when using `hidden` is the unintended consequence of hiding content if the parent has a fixed height.

Other properties that, once applied to the parent, can help fix this behaviour are:

- `float: left / right`
- `position: absolute`
- `display: flex / grid`

You can test all of them here: http://jsfiddle.net/XB9wX/1/.

I should add that, as usual, Internet Explorer is the exception. More specifically, in IE 7 margins do not collapse when some kind of layout is specified for the parent element, such as `width`.

Sources: Sitepoint's article *[Collapsing Margins](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins)*

Comment: note that padding can also affect this if it's not zero value

Comment: Note that `overflow: auto` can cause scrollbars to appear in the parent element, rather than letting overflow content overflow as per `overflow: visible`.

Comment: 'overflow: auto' doesn't seem to work in Chrome v44.

Comment: @tkane2000 Works for me with Chrome 51.

Comment: Any value of `flex` different from its default will also disable margin collapse

Comment: `display: flow-root` might be the prefered method once browser support picks up a bit.

Comment: Hi, when you say "Using a padding or border will prevent collapse only in the latter case" , do you mean using them on the parent or on the child?

Comment: so  regular div or display: block => margin collapsed but  display: inline-block with width: 100%; => margin not collpased

Answer (score 81):

One neat trick to disable margin collapsing that has no visual impact, as far as I know, is setting the padding of the parent to `0.05px`:

```
.parentClass {
    padding: 0.05px;
}
```

The padding is no longer 0 so collapsing won't occur anymore but at the same time the padding is small enough that visually it will round down to 0.

If some other padding is desired, then apply padding only to the "direction" in which margin collapsing is not desired, for example `padding-top: 0.05px;`.

**Working example:**

```css
.noCollapse {
  padding: 0.05px;
}

.parent {
  background-color: red;
  width: 150px;
}

.children {
  margin-top: 50px;

  background-color: lime;      
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<h3>Border collapsing</h3>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="children">
  </div>
</div>

<h3>No border collapsing</h3>
<div class="parent noCollapse">
  <div class="children">
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit:** changed the value from `0.1` to `0.05`. As Chris Morgan mentioned in a comment bellow, and from [this small test](https://codepen.io/surdu/pen/GWMNZK), it seems that indeed Firefox takes the `0.1px` padding into consideration. Though, `0.05px` seemes to do the trick.

Comment: This is my favorite solution. You could even include this as a default style. Why not? `*{padding-top:0.1px}`. Are we sure it works in all browsers though?

Comment: Worked pretty nice so far for me, but I don't claim to have tested it thoroughly in most browsers.

Comment: Very nice solution, it seems to work as expected on most browsers. Thanks for sharing it!

Comment: This is a dodgy solution as it *does* add extra pixels in various circumstances, due to high-DPI displays and subpixel calculations. (Firefox has done subpixel layout for ages, I believe other browsers have comparatively recently followed suit.)

Comment: `0.05px` seems still like a specific choice, not a random browser trickery number, I'd prefer `0.01px`.

Comment: `.01px` is too low and doesn't work (at least in Chrome). `.05px` seems to work the most consistently for now, and is still mostly imperceptible. Depending on layout, `margin-top: -.05px` may be an option to offset the padding, if it's super critical.

Comment: Just for completion: `0.01px` works in latest Chrome 102 and Firefox 102 on macOS.

Comment: This solution seems too clever, it is not so easy to understand compared to other options, so it has no place in the production code

Comment: This answer is outdated, use `display: flex-root`

Comment: Only works for parent-child situations and not peer-peer elements.

Answer (score 69):

You can also use the good old micro clearfix for this.

```
#container::before, #container::after{
    content: ' ';
    display: table;
}
```

See updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XB9wX/97/

Comment: Have turned my answer into a community wiki. Please feel free to extend it with your answer. Thanks.

Comment: I don't get it, when I view that example the margins are collapsing (only 10px vertical space between the divs instead of 20px)

Comment: This helps only in removing the collapse between siblings that all have this clearfix applied. I've forked the example to demonstrate this: http://jsfiddle.net/dpyuyg07/ --- and even that is not the whole story. It only removes the collapse of margins stemming from children of the elements where you've applied that fix. If you would add a margin on the container itself the margins would still collapse, which can be seen in this fork: http://jsfiddle.net/oew7qsjx/

Comment: I can put this even more precisely: the clearfix method only prevents margin collapse between parents and children. It does not affect the collapse between adjacent siblings.

Comment: I think I now understand Bootstrap's tendency to fill the DOM with `:before` and `:after` elements. I have now added this rule to my stylesheet: `div:before, div:after{content: ' '; display: table;}`. Fantastic. Suddenly stuff starts to behave as expected.

Comment: The margin is still collapsing for me in both Chrome and Firefox: https://imgur.com/a/Xv18D

Comment: Does not work for self-closing element, such as `<input>`.

Answer (score 28):

Actually, there is one that works flawlessly:

display: flex;
flex-direction: column;

> *as long as you can live with supporting only IE10 and up*

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
    background: #ddd;
    width: 15em;
}

.square {
    margin: 15px;
    height: 3em;
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: For this to work as a generic solution, one has to add an extra `<div>` within the `.container`, otherwise the `.container` will control the box-model of its children. For example, inline elements will become full-width block elements; if they have margins those will also be margin-collapsed.

Answer (score 24):

`overflow:hidden` prevents collapsing margins but it's not free of side effects - namely it... hides overflow.

Apart form this and what you've mentioned you just have to learn live with it and learn for this day when they are actually useful (comes every 3 to 5 years).

Comment: Have turned my answer into a community wiki. I think I did cover the side-effect you mentioned in the last two lines of the second paragraph: _Perhaps the only difference when using hidden is the unintended consequence of hiding content if the parent has a fixed height_. But if you feel that needs further clarification, please feel free to contribute. Thanks.

Comment: `overflow: auto` is good to use to prevent hidden overflow and still prevent collapsing margins.

Comment: @Gavin, `overflow:auto;` made my content area gain a scrollbar on some pages.

Answer (score 12):

| CSS* | Fixes |
| --- | --- |
| ``` display: flow-root; ``` | ✅ Parent element collapse ❌ Sibling element collapse |
| ``` display: flex; flex-direction: column; ``` | ✅ Parent element collapse ✅ Sibling element collapse |

**Modern browsers (excluding IE11) support [`display: flow-root`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#flow-root) and [`display: flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout).*

#### Examples

```css
section {
  background: green;
  outline: 2px solid purple;
}

p {
  background: yellow;
  margin: 1em 0;
}

section.flow-root {
  display: flow-root;
}

section.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<h2>Default</h2>  
<section>
  <p>Paragraph 1</p>
  <p>Paragraph 2</p>
</section>

<h2><code>flow-root</code> (Fixes only container)</h2>
<section class="flow-root">
  <p>Paragraph 1</p>
  <p>Paragraph 2</p>
</section>

<h2><code>flex</code> (Fixes both container & siblings)</h2>
<section class="flex">
  <p>Paragraph 1</p>
  <p>Paragraph 2</p>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit [AnthumChris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4035845/anthumchris). This makes me wonder if there is any technique that prevent Sibling collapse while preserving the Parent element collapse. That would make our answer the most flexible and complete solution!

Answer (score 9):

I know that this is a very old post but just wanted to say that using flexbox on a parent element would disable margin collapsing for its child elements.

Comment: Not only for its child elements – it also prevents margin collapsing between parent and first and last child.

Answer (score 8):

Every webkit based browser should support the properties `-webkit-margin-collapse`. There are also subproperties to only set it for the top or bottom margin. You can give it the values collapse (default), discard (sets margin to 0 if there is a neighboring margin), and separate (prevents margin collapse).

I've tested that this works on 2014 versions of Chrome and Safari. Unfortunately, I don't think this would be supported in IE because it's not based on webkit.

Read [Apple's Safari CSS Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001266--webkit-margin-bottom-collapse) for a full explanation.

If you check [Mozilla's CSS webkit extensions page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference/Webkit_Extensions), they list these properties as proprietary and recommend not to use them. This is because they're likely not going to go into standard CSS anytime soon and only webkit based browsers will support them.

Comment: This is nice because it helps us iron out an inconsistency in how Safari and Chrome deal with margins.

Comment: Looks like the property `-webkit-margin-collapse` was removed in Chrome v85. I used this in some tools and the tests are now failing.

Answer (score 3):

To prevent margin collapsing between siblings, add `display: inline-block;` to one of the siblings (one is enough though you can add it to both).

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
{
 display:flex;
 flex-direction:column;
}
```

or

```
{
   display:grid;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem with margin collapse because of parent having `position` set to relative. Here are list of commands you can use to disable margin collapsing.

## HERE IS PLAYGROUND TO TEST

Just try to assign any `parent-fix*` class to `div.container` element, or any class `children-fix*` to `div.margin`. Pick the one that fits your needs best.

When

- margin **collapsing** is **disabled**, `div.absolute` with red background will be positioned at the very top of the page.
- **margin is collapsing** `div.absolute` will be positioned at the same Y coordinate as `div.margin`

```css
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

.container {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50px;
  right: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 5px solid #F00;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.margin {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #444;
  margin-top: 50px;
  color: #FFF;
}

/* Here are some examples on how to disable margin 
   collapsing from within parent (.container) */
.parent-fix1 { padding-top: 1px; }
.parent-fix2 { border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0, 0);}
.parent-fix3 { overflow: auto;}
.parent-fix4 { float: left;}
.parent-fix5 { display: inline-block; }
.parent-fix6 { position: absolute; }
.parent-fix7 { display: flex; }
.parent-fix8 { -webkit-margin-collapse: separate; }
.parent-fix9:before {  content: ' '; display: table; }

/* Here are some examples on how to disable margin 
   collapsing from within children (.margin) */
.children-fix1 { float: left; }
.children-fix2 { display: inline-block; }
```

```html
<div class="container parent-fix1">
  <div class="margin children-fix">margin</div>
  <div class="absolute"></div>
</div>
```

Here is **[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/buksy/a6wseknw/)** with example you can edit

Answer (score 0):

For your information you could use
grid but with side effects :)

```
.parent {
  display: grid
}
```