# Margin-top affects to another element besides

Tags: css

When I give a `top-margin` to `.galeria` element, why I get also the same `top-margin` in `.sorial-grande` element?

http://sorialconstrucciones.com/trabajos

```
.sorial-grande {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: url("/drawing.svg");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    height: 337px;
    background-position: center center;
  }
  .galeria {
    padding: 40px;
    clear: both;
    /*margin-top: 350px;*/
    img {
      width: 207px;
      margin-right: 10px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
  }


<div class="sorial-grande"></div>
<section class="galeria">
  <img src="/images/00.jpg"></img>
  <img src="/images/02.jpg"></img>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is commonly known as margin collapse. Essentialy, as it goes on [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing), "Top and bottom margins of blocks are sometimes combined (collapsed) into a single margin whose size is the largest of the margins combined into it, a behavior known as margin collapsing."

There are a few [ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19718634/how-to-disable-margin-collapsing) to get around it. In your case, easiest would be to add `padding-top:1px` to `<main>` tag

Answer (score 0):

Change it from margin-top to padding-top

```
.galeria {
    padding-top: 350px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think somewhere is repeating code because the watch file .css, I see more properties that you mention. If that is true, I think that commenting out these two lines, will fix your problem (if that's what you want).

```
main .sorial-grande {
   /* position: absolute; this line */
}
```

and

```
main #galeria { 
    /* padding: 222px 40px 40px; */
}
```