# How to remove top margin from a website with nested containers?

Tags: css, margin, user-agent

For some reason User Agent overrides my css, and puts a margin on top of a website i'm creating. I've searched stackoverflow for answers, but none seem to solve my problem.

Here's an example:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>EXAMPLE</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="site-wrapper">
    <div class="menu">
        <div class="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">EXAMPLE</a></li>
                <li ><a href="/spots">EXAMPLE</a></li>

                    <li ><a data-method="delete" href="/users/sign_out" rel="nofollow">EXAMPLE</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>      
    </div>  
        <div class="content">
            <p id="notice"></p>

<div class="container">

</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html,
body {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  margin: 0px;
  display: block;
}

.site-wrapper {
    display: block;
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.nav {
    background-color: red;
}

.content {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}

.menu {
    font-weight: 400;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-115px;
    position:absolute;
width:100%;
text-align: center;
font-size: 12px;
letter-spacing: .75;
}


ul {
list-style: none;
line-height: 40px;
padding: 0px;
display: block;
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/8IO5ux16x40UhKeSDJvN?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paragraphs have a default margin. Eliminate it:

```
p {
    margin:0;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/t50jyL2x/)**

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by margin collapsing - parent elements don't have margin (or padding) so paragraph's margin is used.

You could either remove margin from the paragraph as suggested by [j08691](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25511189/206614) or you can prevent margin collapsing by adding styling to parent containers - see this question: [How to disable margin-collapsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19718634/how-to-disable-margin-collapsing)

For example this will help:

```
.content {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to set margin for all elements

```
 *{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
 }
```