# Gap on top of h1 title

Tags: html, css

I want to style a toolbar similar to the android toolbar.
First I defined a header :

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #E5E5E5;
  font-family: 'RobotoDraft', 'sans-serif';
}
header {
  background: #FF0000;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
h1 {
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bot: 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Home</h1>
</header>
```

What I dont understand now is the **small gap at the top of the title**:

[image: Gap on top of H1 title]

I set the padding and the margin to be zero. so why do I get this gap at the top of my header?

Comment: Has nothing to do with your question, but note that `margin-bot` does not exist. It's called `margin-bottom`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gap on the top of your title is created because of the top margin of the `<h1>` tag.

This is called [**collapsing margins**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing). You can see here for ways to disable it : [How to disable margin-collapsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19718634/how-to-disable-margin-collapsing).

And for example set `overflow:hidden;` on the parent `<header>` element :

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #E5E5E5;
  font-family: 'RobotoDraft', 'sans-serif';
}
header {
  background: #FF0000;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
h1 {
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Home</h1>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's the `margin` on your `h1`.

Change your `margin` to be `padding`:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ewkr9qw9/)

```
h1 {
    padding: 10px 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a margin on your h1 selector.

This was the line that causes it:

```
margin-top: 10px;
```

Check out this [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5qpsdvky/)

Answer (score 1):

It has a gap because the `h1` within your `header` has `margin-top: 10px`. Set it to 0px and it the gap will not appear anymore.

Also as a side note, `margin-bot` is not a valid css property. It's `margin-bottom`.

```css
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #E5E5E5;
    font-family: 'RobotoDraft', 'sans-serif';
}

header {
    background: #FF0000;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


h1 {
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <h1>Home</h1>
</header>
```