# MarginTop applying to the body

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a website, I'm trying to integrate a little addon.

I have a problem that i already faced but i forgot how to resolve it.

this is the site : http://www.journaldunet.com/solutions/mobilite/ios-9.shtml

Basically, when you add a margin-top to the elements inside the body, this margin-top is applied also to the body. I have actually no idea how to fix it.

The site is responsive so I can't do a because it's won't be responsive anymore

```
#mydiv{
position:absolute;
width:1000px;
margin:auto;
}
```

Do someone have an idea?

**EDIT : Found the solution. overflow isn't working, so i had to do a little trick (which in this case works). It's not clean, but it do the trick.**

```
body{
padding-top:1px;
margin-top:-1px;
}
```

thx

Comment: Share your code, so what you are telling is impossible

Comment: Could you narrow your problem by editing [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/421o3yd1/)? It seems margin-top is NOT propagated to the body. Something else have to cause it.

Comment: It was a classic margin-collapsing problem. I didn't knew this was the name of the problem so i couldn't find proper answer. Now with a little google search about margin collapsing I found the solution there : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19718634/how-to-disable-margin-collapsing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The whole CSS is valid:

```css
#mydiv{
position:absolute;
width:1000p;
margin-auto;
}
```

Change it to:

```css
#mydiv{
  position: absolute;
  width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Errors:

1. `1000p` is wrong. Should be `1000px`.
2. `margin-auto` is wrong. Use `margin: auto`.

**Solution** to your issue. Try giving this to the CSS to fix:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

The reason I ask you to reset the `margin` is by default, as per [CSS 2.1 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/sample.html), the default margin is `8px`. I have added `padding: 0;` because to make sure that other CSS shouldn't affect the padding. Hope it is clear.

Comment: yes this is my bad, i fast created the message  (and use a new keyboard) so I mistipped. Anyway,  I can't do that cause the site is responsive and a position absolute with a width will brake it.

Comment: You have the `position` and please remove it!

Comment: Your post is just a notice about a simple typo, not an answer to the problem, which is passing margin-top to the body for some reason. Unless you have anything to explain, I suggest you comment instead.

Comment: @JanTuroň Sorry, forgot to add the solution. I commented it asking the OP to remove `position: absolute`. Can you kindly check the answer again?

Comment: Your post would be worth answer if you explained (preferably with reference to manual) WHY the position is problem here.

Comment: For example in case of your solution you could point out that the default margin for body is 8px with reference to [this link](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/sample.html). There is no point adding padding: 0. *it works* is not an answer. Explanation is needed to know the source of the problem.

Comment: That looks much better.

Answer (score 2):

Your CSS is wrong:
1000p; => correct: 1000px;
margin-auto; => margin:auto;

Change your css:

```
#mydiv{
  position: absolute;
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: XXXXXXX;
}
```

Comment: yes this is my bad, i fast created the message  (and use a new keyboard) so I mistipped. Anyway,  I can't do that cause the site is responsive and a position absolute with a width will brake it.

Comment: This is not the OP ask. OP said that body applies the margin of the childers