# Full height background-color on list item requires padding or overflow?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a solution for my problem, but it doesn't seem right. I want to know what's going on.

Nested list item's background colour doesn't extend to the bottom even though there's no margin on it (see the gap below the blue background in the screen shots). The paragraph inside does have a margin. But I've tried to reproduce this outside of my app (which uses Bootstrap) and I can't. In Firebug I tried turning off all CSS except that which was necessary to show the problem (i.e., the background-color and border -- see 2nd image), but it makes no difference. Seen in Chrome and Firefox.

The fix is either adding bottom padding or `overflow-y:auto;` to the inner list item. But why? Has anyone encountered something like this?

I can't post all the code here, but the HTML at least is something like this:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="dropdown open">
         <ul class="dropdown-menu notification-list">   
                    <li class="notification-new">
                        <div class="text-muted">01/13/2015</div>
                        <p>Check out the new features coming to the 2015.1 release <a href="javascript:void(0)">here</a>!</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="notification-new">
                        <div class="text-muted">12/24/2014<button class="close" type="button"><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button></div>
                        <p>Upcoming server maintenance scheduled for 11:00pm PST.</p>
                    </li>
```

[image: Unwanted gap below blue background]

[image: With almost all CSS turned off]

[Update] Here is a simplified, non-Bootstrap version. Why no gaps in this one?

```css
        ul {
            width: 300px;
            border: 1px solid red;
            float: left;
        }

        li.sub {
            border: 1px solid green;
            background-color: yellow;
            padding: 8px 8px 0;
        }

p { margin:10px; /* no gaps with or without this */ }
```

```html
 <ul>
        <li><p>item 1</p>
            <ul>
                <li class="sub">
                    <div>
                        something
                    </div>
                    <p>
                        stuff
                    </p>
                </li>
                <li class="sub">
                    <div>
                        something
                    </div>
                    <p>
                        stuff
                    </p>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>thing
            <ul>
                <li class="sub">
                    nuther
                </li>
            </ul>

        </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Your asking a question that could be a structure problem or more likely a CSS property problem, but you have not shared the CSS for the classes. So, please share the CSS. Also it is possible that parent CSS/structure above yout code could be affecting it.

Comment: @DMSJax, I realize that. It's just difficult get all the right CSS to put here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spacing is occurring because of the margins in the `p` elements inside the `li`s, specifically the bottom margin.

This behavior is defined as 'collapsing margins'. More info here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins

You can see this by setting them to 0.

```
.notification-new p{
  margin:0;
}
```

Live example: http://www.bootply.com/wlfIl3RziC

Full code below:

```css
.notification-new {
  background-color:red;
}

.notification-new p{
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li class="dropdown open">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu notification-list">   
      <li class="notification-new">
        <div class="text-muted">01/13/2015</div>
        <p>Check out the new features coming to the 2015.1 release <a href="javascript:void(0)">here</a>!</p>
      </li>
      <li class="notification-new">
        <div class="text-muted">12/24/2014<button class="close" type="button"><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button></div>
        <p>Upcoming server maintenance scheduled for 11:00pm PST.</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see the issue in my non-Bootstrap version, so if it only happens in Bootstrap I want to know why. I didn't know you could do runnable code snippets in Stack Overflow. Let me try that...

Comment: Added a simpler code snippet to my question. If it's standard behaviour, why no gaps in that version?

Comment: @WesReimer That's because in your non-bootstrap example there are borders on the `li`s. This prevents the margins from collapsing.

Comment: The accepted answer here lists the most common ways to prevent collapsing margins: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19718634/how-to-disable-margin-collapsing

Comment: Ah, the lights are coming on. Specifically, a bottom border would prevent the issue in this case. Thank you!