# Why is the margin of my child html element outside the parent

Tags: html, css

I have a child element (h1 in my example) inside a parent div.

Why does the margin of the child appear to be outside of the parent.

The example below:

The child has a padding of 30px and a red border round it as expected.
The div has a yellow background but I expected it to be of height 100 + 30 + the h1 + 30 + 100.

```css
div {
    background-color: yellow;
}

h1 {
    margin: 100px;
    padding: 30px;
    border: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <h1>Child</h1>
</div>
```

Interestingly if I put a border round the div as in the example below - it behaves as I expected.  I know I can work round this, but I would like to know what is going on?

```css
div {
    background-color: yellow;
    border: 5px solid green;
}

h1 {
    margin: 100px;
    padding: 30px;
    border: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <h1>Child</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Its called "margin-collapse" Helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19718634/how-to-disable-margin-collapsing

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's "margin collapsing" which can seem confusing at first.

I recommend you read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing

Comment: Ah ha.  So I am right in thinking a margin means - I will guarantee you have this much space - but I may eat some of the space of things around me as long as nothing else (e.g. a border) is in the the way.

Comment: Yeah, that's a pretty accurate description I think :-)

Answer (score 0):

This can be *fixed* by applying `display: inline-block` on the div or the h1. However, I highly recommend using `padding` on the div in this case, that should solve the problem permanently.

Comment: However if you increase the padding, then the border around the h1 will continue to stretch out, which may be undesired.

Comment: @mikeyq6 Does it, though? I tried with the examples provided by the OP and was not able to reproduce that regardless of the amount of padding provided.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your answer, I thought you had said padding on the h1. My apologies, you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

> **Empty blocks**: If there is no border, padding, inline content, height,
>   or min-height to separate a block's margin-top from its margin-bottom,
>   then its top and bottom margins collapse. [Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing)

You can use the `outline` css property for consistent behavior.

```css
div {
    background-color: yellow;
    outline: 5px solid green;
}

h1 {
    margin: 100px;
    padding: 30px;
    border: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <h1>Child</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: This does not work for the top/bottom margin - it's still outside the parent

Answer (score 0):

When you set the border that means you are telling the DIV container it's boundary.

you have to assign the widths and floats.

```
float: left;
width: 100%;
```

Right now the DIV is starting from top. But showing background from the mid.

Answer (score -2):

```css
div {
    background-color: yellow;
    padding:100px;
}

h1 {
    padding: 30px;
    border: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <h1>Child</h1>
</div>
```

Or this

```css
div {
    background-color: yellow;
    padding:1px;
}

h1 {
    margin:100px;
    padding: 30px;
    border: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <h1>Child</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. Instead of how to achieve the effect, the question is asking why the behaviour (margin of `h1` ends up outside of `div`) happens.

Comment: you'd rather explain why your answer would solve his problem