# How do I fix margin issue in CSS?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a basic landing page with HTML & CSS where the whole header background is an image.

Here's my CSS code:

```
body,html {
  height: 100%;
  background: honeydew;
}
header {
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/myBucket/myBG.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;

}
```

When I add an `h1` or any form of text onto the `header` my webpage creates a large margin off the top of the browser. I also cannot edit my text at all.

Here is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>myTitle</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="pencil.ico" />
    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>

  <body>
    <header>
      <h1>Hello!</h1>
      <h3>Welcome!</h3>
    </header>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Use of jQuery Syntax) -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's my webpage prior to any addition of text:
[image]

Now here it is after text was added:
[image]

What seems to be the issue?

Comment: The issue seems to be margin collapsing and is the CSS box model's default behaviour. See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1. This css should take care of the margin/padding that you're seeing when you add an h1 element:**

```
h1 {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
```

To eliminate the spacing around your header background image you'll need to ensure that the `html`, `body` and `header` elements have no margin or padding:

```
html, body, header {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
}
```

You could also use something like this to get rid of the default padding/margin on all elements:

```
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

Many developers will override browser default styles with a css reset like [normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/).

**2. Your main.css should be loaded after the Bootstrap stylesheet.**

You should ensure that you're loading your styles after Bootstrap.css. adjust your html to match this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Student Sanctuary</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="pencil.ico" />


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <header>
      <h1>Hello!</h1>
      <h3>Welcome!</h3>
    </header>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Use of jQuery Syntax) -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you don't load your custom css styles after Bootstrap, then you'll have to add `!important` to you styles in order to override the Bootstrap stylesheet.

**3. Here's a working solution in a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hpzoj9wk/) with a cool cat photo**

Comment: none of my css code towards my text are being accepted. they are just being ignored. and the real issue is the margin from the top of my header back ground image to the browser. it still appears when i add text to the header

Comment: see edit regarding header background image margin/padding

Comment: see edit related to bootstrap css - your main.css file should come after your the bootstrap css.

Comment: your jsfiddle file has the same issue. the margin is still showing

Comment: jsfiddle doesn't allow you to load external resources before you custom css. See updated fiddle.

Comment: @AndrewHendrie "This space is there because of the browsers default stylesheet" is not correct. It is there due to margin collapsing. Bootstrap already includes normalize and therefore body and html elements' margins are already removed.

Comment: Additionally, there is a large difference between normalize.css and reset.css. The suggested CSS rule you provided is a reset and does not add up well with normalize.css' behaviour which is included in bootstrap.

Comment: please elaborate on why the suggested CSS rule does not 'add up well' with normalize.css. is there a better way to achieve the desired result?

Comment: @AndrewHendrie I guess "add up well" was not the right wording - and I have to thank you because I just checked and it has no effect on normalize.css behaviour at all due to all rules being declared more explicit :) Still, I suspect it is not needed when using bootstrap as the body will have its margin removed already, no? As for the solution itself - I'm pretty sure that margin collapsing is the primary suspect as can be seen in my answer. (Which I updated - the note seemed out of place anyway)

Answer (score 2):

You need to override bootstrap's CSS like this.

```
header h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

If you want to set all `h1` with one rule, do like this

```
h1 {
  margin: 0 !important;
}
```

If you make sure your CSS rules loads *after* bootstraps you can remove the `!important`

---

Snippet

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  background: honeydew;
}
header {
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/myBucket/myBG.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

header h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7"
    crossorigin="anonymous">

    <header>
      <h1>Hello!</h1>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is [margin collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing) in effect and the CSS box model's default behaviour.** In particular collapsing margins between parent and child elements where `H1`'s margin is applied on the `header` element.

The common solution to overcome margin collapsing is to declare an `overflow` rule, a top padding, or a border on `header`. Since the header has a fixed height `overflow: hidden` would be the most fitting. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19719427/580651) for more details and further possible solutions.

Setting the `top-margin` to `0` on `h1` has the same effect in this particular case but is not very useful if you actually **want** to apply a top-margin to it later on.

```css
body,html {
  height: 100%;
  background: honeydew;
}
header {
  height: 100vh;
  background: #39C;
  overflow: hidden; /* overcome margin collapsing */
}
header h1:first-child {
  /* apply any margins - will not affect header anymore */
}
```

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Hello!</h1>
    <h3>Welcome!</h3>
  </header>
</body>
```