# Container shifts when adding margin to child

Tags: css, margin

I've got two div elements with my classes container and innercontainer with the following CSS styles.

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}
.innercontainer {
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="innercontainer"></div>
</div>
```

What I expected was a red rectangle almost in the center of a green square.

What I got was a red rectangle on top of a green square. It shifted my rectangle 80px down but why does it put my square below the rectangle?

If I put a border around the square everything goes as expected. The same is if I say `position: fixed` in my container class.

I thought block elements orient themselves at the border of their surrounding container. In this case it seems to me as if innerconainer orients itself at the body?

Comment: Where is the width of the innercontainer? no width usuall means as wide as possible unless something is inside of it.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to [margin collapse](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins):

> The top margin of an in-flow block element collapses with its first
>   in-flow block-level child's top margin if the element has no top
>   border, no top padding, and the child has no clearance.

There are [multiple ways](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19718634/1529630) to prevent this, e.g. by using inline-block instead of block.

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}
.innercontainer {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="innercontainer"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to [collapsing margins](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins) your div gets pushed down.

Set `overflow:auto` on the `container`

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  overflow: auto;
}

.innercontainer {
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-top: 80px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="innercontainer">
    </div>
  </div>
```

or use `padding-top` on the `container`

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  padding-top: 80px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.innercontainer {
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="innercontainer">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide `padding` to the parent container to shift it to the center.
proving `margin` from the `innercontainer` will start taking `margin` from top and if it exceeds the height, it will overflow the parent container.

So, what you are trying to do would somewhat work like this:

```css
  .container {
    padding:35px;   
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: green;     
  }

 .innercontainer {
   height: 30px;
   background-color: red;
   margin: 80px 0 0 0;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="innercontainer"></div>
</div>
```