# My child-div's margin is outside of its parent's content

Tags: html, css

Well, everything seems to be positioned and I don't understand why the child div's margin  is outside of its parent's content :

[image: As highlighted with firebug]

With calculated style of parent:

[image: calculated style of parent]

And of child:

[image: calculated style of child]

Can you tell me what's wrong ?

Comment: Post your HTML and CSS

Comment: `position` not set? `line-height` set to `28px` could also affect display

Comment: Please post a JSfiddle so that we can work on your problem.

Comment: Looks like margin collapsing, see [how to fix it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19718634/how-to-disable-margin-collapsing).

Comment: @Pangloss : +1 you were right : margin collasping. I added an `overflow: auto` and the problem is solved. Thanks. I will take some time to understand exactly why and how this instruction solved my problem.

Comment: It can be a little confusing, but not very hard to understand, see - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing