# css: margin-top causes scrollbar

Tags: html, css

The `h1` element causes a scrollbar to appear. Can anyone explain me why?

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
header {
  height:10%;
}
section {
  height:90%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>
    Hello
  </h1>
</header>
<section>
  test
</section>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That's because

- `h1` have some vertical margin by default, usually `0.67em`.
- The top margin of `h1` collapses
- `height` never includes the height of the margin area

Since the top margin of `h1` collapses, it behaves like the margin belonged to the `header` instead of the `h1`. Since the content height of the `h1` is `10%`, its total height will be `calc(10% + 0.67em)`.

That's why there is overflow.

If you remove the top margin but leave the bottom one there is no problem, because the bottom one does not collapse, due to the non-`auto` `height`. From [Collapsing margins](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins),

> Two margins are *adjoining* if [...] both belong to vertically-adjacent
>   box edges, [... e.g.]
>
> - top margin of a box and top margin of its first in-flow child
> - bottom margin of a last in-flow child and bottom
>     margin of its parent if the parent has `auto` computed height.

So you can do any of the following

- Remove `h1`'s top margin
- [Prevent the margin collapse](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19718634/1529630)
- Propose a `box-sizing: margin-box` to the CSS Working Group. It will probably be rejected.

Comment: this is actually the best answer. But some questions: how can a margin collapse if I have only one element with margin? Second, which solution do you recommended among your suggestions?

Comment: I mentioned `margin-bottom` because in many (most?) cases there will be elements below an `h1`. The question I assume provided a highly simplified example. In actual use, the `margin-bottom` may have an impact. But I agree that only `margin-top` matters in this case.

Comment: @Matthew If you don't need the margin, I would remove it. Otherwise I would use `h1{ display: inline-block }` or similar to prevent margin collapse.

Comment: @Michael_B Yes, if there was some content after the `h1`, the `margin-bottom` would still increase the distance between them. I didn't mean it's completely ignored.

Comment: @Oriol can you explain me how margin collapse if only one element has margin (h1). Which margins are collpasing? margin-top of h1 element with what?

Comment: The top margins of `h1` and `header` collapse. So the behavior will be like if `h1` had no top margin, and `header` had a top margin equal to the maximum of its top margin (0) and `h1`'s one.

Comment: @Oriol so you consider that header HAS a top-margin, which is 0. And that it collapses with the top-margin of h1. What confused me is that for me header had just no top-margin...

Answer (score 7):

Because the `h1` comes with a margin, applied by the [*default style sheet*](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/sample.html).

When you add this margin (often `margin-top: .67em` and `margin-bottom: .67em`) to the `height: 100%` in your code, this exceeds the viewport height, launching a vertical scroll bar.

Give the `h1` a `margin: 0`.

Whether you use `box-sizing: content-box` or `border-box`, the margin space will always be added to your `height` declaration.

If you want to add space around your `h1` without adding height, use padding instead of margin, along with `box-sizing: border-box`. Here are some implementation options: https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

Answer (score 1):

`h1` by default has a margin applied.

[image]

Comment: I know that h1 has a margin. But why does it cause a scrollbar? header is 10%, and section is 90% of viewport. h1 is contained in header.

Answer (score 1):

```css
*
{
  margin:0px auto;
}
html, body {
  margin: 0 ;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
header {
  height:10%;
}
section {
  height:90%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>
    Hello
  </h1>
</header>
<section>

  test
</section>
```

Just add universal selector and make the margin `*{margin:0px auto;}` . Hope it will work

Comment: @AliMottaghiPour Its a good practice to use`*{margin:0px auto`,`auto` to let the browser calculate the margins

Comment: for reset css you must use * { margin:0; }

Comment: @AliMottaghiPour you are absolutely right,but universal selector `*` uses **flow down** technique, whatever you define here will be inherited that I want to say.

Answer (score 1):

h1 tag in a block level element has some margin.

To remove such type of extra margin and padding, it is recommended to reset all elements margin and padding to 0.

This can be done by :

```
 * {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
 }
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
header {
  height:10%;
}
section {
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>
    Hello
  </h1>
</header>
<section>
  test
</section>
```