# Keeping a div's vertical spacing when it collapses underneath a floated item

Tags: html, css

I have a div/icon (#user-initials) floated to the left of two other divs: .employee-name and .status.

If the .employee-name line happens to consist of two lines, the .status div gets pushed to the left side, underneath #user-initials. This works fine.

What I'm trying to do is keep the original spacing on top of .status that it had from .employee-name (11px). Once it's below the floated item, however, its margin gets cut to about 6px. See screenshot below for a better idea:

[image: Margins are correct on top image example, not on bottom]

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kfjtnk9r/1/

```css
.container {
  width: 220px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.user_img_color,
.user_img_color_large {
  background: #8aa943;
  border-radius: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  float: left;
  font-size: 15px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 40px;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.employee-name {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
.status {
  margin-top: 4px;
}
.welcome-message {
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 15px;
}
div.status-indicator {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 8px;
  width: 8px;
  content: " ";
  line-height: 14px;
  background: #f5c002;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin: 0 2px 0 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
div.status-message {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 14px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="clearfix">
    <div id="user-initials" class="inline-block">
      <div class="user_img_color user_img_color-pending">TH</div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="employee-name">Name Namington</div>

  <div class="status">
    <div class="status-indicator status-indicator-complete"></div>
    <div class="status-message">Status Message</div>
  </div>


  <div class="welcome-message">
    Welcome message Welcome message
    <br>Welcome message Welcome message
  </div>

</div>
```

Any help would be much appreciated... I've tried everything.

Edit: added better screenshot image

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wk79s3qf/1/ is the best solution done by **Simon Knittel** but you need to check the supported browsers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable margin-collapsing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19718634/how-to-disable-margin-collapsing)

Comment: There's no error here other than perception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution**
You can wrap the icon, name and status message into a container with `display: flex;` (called *flexbox*) like this https://jsfiddle.net/wk79s3qf/1/

**Flexbox**
*Flexbox* is a new CSS3 feature which allows you to easily create grid-like layouts while not needing `margin` and `float` and other tricks.

**Cheat Sheet**
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

**Browser Support**
http://caniuse.com/flexbox

Comment: I really appreciate it, however, I'm trying to keep the status message flush to the left once it's under the icon. Do you know if that's possible with Flex? I'll be playing around with it.

Comment: Can you rephrase that? I don't really get what you want.

Comment: The "Status Message" line -- I'm trying to get that to be left aligned underneath the "TH" green circle.

Comment: Wasn't that the issue you wanted to prevent? Sorry, but can you do a small drawing or something like that?

Comment: Sorry! The issue I was trying to prevent was the vertical spacing, not horizontal --- the "TH" icon being floated disregards the top margin on the  "Status Message", once it gets pushed below it. So there's the correct amount of vertical spacing between name and status in the first image example and in the second there's too little vertical spacing.

Answer (score 0):

Your `.status` rule has in fact a `margin: 4px`. Change that to 10px (or whatever you like) and it will work:

https://jsfiddle.net/c036a3mg/1/

Comment: unfortunately, the same problem persists -- only now when the name is just one line there's extra spacing

Comment: well, but that's the "real" spacing - it just seems more below the text (as opposed to below the image) because of the line height of the text above it, which includes space for the descenders of letters like j, y, g etc., whereas the image doesn't have extra bottom space like that.