# <a> tag gets height - why is that?

Tags: html, css

Why is that `<a>` tag gets height in below example [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sz3008up/5/)

I guess that's why my margins on feature class don't work as expected.

Sample of code

```css
.feature {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.feature__caption {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  color: #c158ad;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding: 2% 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="col span_4_of_12">
  <figure class="feature">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="shoes">
      <figcaption class="feature__caption">ACCESSORIES</figcaption>
    </a>
  </figure>
  <figure class="feature">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="shoes">
      <figcaption class="feature__caption">LATEST FASHION</figcaption>
    </a>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: That renders exactly the way I would expect from the code. I have no idea what you are expecting, so explaining why it doesn't look that way is hard.

Comment: Because you put an <img> with a certain width and height (from the image name I am guessing it is 350x150) inside of the <a>?

Comment: @Quentin dunno why <a> tag has exactly 18px height. What is more important why margins don't work on <figure>. I mean they collapse each other.

Comment: @csm_dev yeah 350x150

Comment: @Przemek85 — Is your question "Why is the distance between the images 10px instead of 20px?"? If so, [it is a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19718634/how-to-disable-margin-collapsing).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you want. Try it out.

```
.feature img {
  display: block;  
}
```

Browsers technically use display: inline (as you can see in the developer tools), for img tags. Anyway images get somehow a special treatment and their default display is very much like the one of an inline-block element.

Comment: hell yeah ! Can you explain ?

Comment: @Przemek85 browsers technically use display: inline (as you can see in the developer tools), for img tags.
Anyway images get somehow a special treatment and their default display is very much like the one of an inline-block element.

Comment: @MarcoMagrini, please put your explanation in your answer.