# How to prevent collapsing paddings

Tags: css, padding, overlap

Never heard about collapsing paddings till now but I encounter a curious effect:
https://jsfiddle.net/Sempervivum/vbkL69k1/
When the viewport is narrow so that the labels wrap, the lower labels cover the upper ones a bit.

HTML:

```
<div class="tabbed">
    <label for="tabbed1">Standardfarben1</label>
    <label for="tabbed2">Standardfarben2</label>
    <label for="tabbed3">Standardfarben3</label>
    <label for="tabbed4">Standardfarben4</label>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
        .tabbed label {
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            border-bottom: none;
            border-top-left-radius: 4px;
            border-top-right-radius: 4px;
            padding: 0.25em 0.75em;
            box-shadow: 0 0 0.5em rgba(0,0,0,0.0625);
            background: #fff;
            cursor: pointer;
            box-sizing: border-box;
         }
```

(Of course in the original code the corresponding inputs are there.)
None of the measures recommended for preventing margin collapse helps.
What is the explanation for this effect and how can I fix it?

Comment: I believe you are confusing this with collapsing margins?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable margin-collapsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19718634/how-to-disable-margin-collapsing)

Comment: It has nothing to do with `margin-collapsing`, @zer00ne.

Comment: I don't spend time analyzing a question if it doesn't have a [mcve]. If a question is given more effort, I'll do likewise. @AndreiGheorghiu

Comment: I understand that, @zer00ne. But should you be marking as duplicate a question you haven't analyzed enough to understand? Shouldn't moving on be the preferred action over a wrong action, reasons aside?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

This is not a collapsing margin problem (or even a collapsing padding). `<label>` has no line height set for it so you just need to set an appropriate line height such as `line-height:1.5;`

Comment: Ah, I see, this is the explanation and the solution. Many thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: This is so wrong, @Rob. You're not addressing the issue, you're avoiding it. :)

Comment: No Anddrei, Rob addresses my issue correctly and his solution works perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

By default, `<label>`s have `display:inline`. Change it to [`display: inline-block`](https://jsfiddle.net/vbkL69k1/1/) and there go your *"collapsing paddings"*.

While `padding` does affect the appearance of the element, its calculated height in the flow of content is dependent on `line-height` value. You either manually adjust that property to accommodate for the possible padding row items might have, so they never overlap, or you use `display:inline-block`.

`line-height` can be expressed in any "length"-type CSS units (`px`, `em`, `in`,...) but, unlike other length properties, accepts unit-less values, considering them `em`.