# Applying margin to centered <div>

Tags: html, css, margin

Today I was trying to make a form (in this case it's a div with class `.second-div`) under another div with this code:

```css
.first-div
{
  width: 25%;
  height: 100px;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-top: 2.5em;
  margin-right: 2em;
}

.second-div
{
  width: 80%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 60px auto 60px auto;
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="first-div"></div>
<div class="second-div"></div>
```

My question is, why doesn't this CSS apply margin-top to the `.second-div` and both of these divs are tied together? What's even stranger to me is that when I apply margin-bottom to the `.first-div`, it works as I'd like it to. Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: It's a known venomenon https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19718634/how-to-disable-margin-collapsing

Comment: Thanks, that first link explained it to me. Also, just to note, I didn't want to know how to fix it, but why does it happen, that's why I started a new post. Anyway, thanks for help, kind sir!

Comment: @SuperDJ this is not exactly margin-collapsing but another kind of issue