# Margin collapse

Tags: html, css

How can I disable margin collapse and get 200px margin without changing the HTML?

code:

```
<style>

div{
  font-size: 100px;
  border: 10px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 100px;

</style>

<body>

  <div>AAAA</div>

  <div>AAAA</div>

</body>
```

Thanks, :D.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by margin collapse? Could you explain a little more what is it that you want to do?

Answer (score -1):

Try adding a padding of 0.1px to the body tag, or any parent tag that will include these 2 divs.

This old trick used to disable collision for most cases.

You may want to see an explanation and other solutions here:
[How to disable margin-collapsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19718634/how-to-disable-margin-collapsing)