# minus margin inside another minus margin div

Tags: html, css

i have given minus margin to `.box2` its working but the inner div in it `.slide` is not working i want the .slide to move above the .box2.

here is the jsfiddle link i have tried please suggest some  ideas.[enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/sL9rfun2/)

is this possible to do with margin itself rather doing with top?
please point out if not possible.

```css
.full-width
{
  width:100%;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  position:relative;
}
.box-width
{
  position:relative;
  max-width:500px;
  margin:0 auto;
  height:150px;
  background:yellow;
}
.box2
{
  max-width:400px;
  margin:-30px auto 0 auto;
  height:150px;
  background:red;
}
.slide
{
  max-width:200px;
  margin:-25px auto 0 auto;
  height:60px;
  background:orange;
}
.slide1{
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="full-width">
    <div class="box-width">
      <div class="slide1"></div>
      <div class="slide1"></div>
      <div class="slide1"></div>
      <div class="slide1"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="full-width">
    <div class="box2">
      <div class="slide"><p> I want this div above than the red div</p ></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue might be related to [margin collapse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing).

> **Parent and first/last child**
>   If there is no border, padding, inline part, block formatting context created, or *clearance* to separate the margin-top of a block from the margin-top of its first child block ... then those margins collapse. The collapsed margin ends up outside the parent.

Adding some sort of clearance between the parent and child prevents the collapse.
Here are a few [methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19718634/how-to-disable-margin-collapsing):

**Padding**

```css
.full-width {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.box-width {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 150px;
  background: yellow;
}

.box2 {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: -30px auto 0 auto;
  height: 150px;
  background: red;
  padding-top: 1px;
}

.slide {
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: -25px auto 0 auto;
  height: 60px;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="full-width">
  <div class="box-width">
    <div class="slide1"></div>
    <div class="slide1"></div>
    <div class="slide1"></div>
    <div class="slide1"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="full-width">
  <div class="box2">
    <div class="slide">
      <p> I want this div above than the red div</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Border**

```css
.full-width {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.box-width {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 150px;
  background: yellow;
}

.box2 {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: -30px auto 0 auto;
  height: 150px;
  background: red;
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
}

.slide {
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: -25px auto 0 auto;
  height: 60px;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="full-width">
  <div class="box-width">
    <div class="slide1"></div>
    <div class="slide1"></div>
    <div class="slide1"></div>
    <div class="slide1"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="full-width">
  <div class="box2">
    <div class="slide">
      <p> I want this div above than the red div</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Pseudo-element**

```css
.full-width {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.box-width {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 150px;
  background: yellow;
}

.box2 {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: -30px auto 0 auto;
  height: 150px;
  background: red;
}

.box2:before,
.box2:after {
  content: ' ';
  display: table;
}

.slide {
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: -25px auto 0 auto;
  height: 60px;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="full-width">
  <div class="box-width">
    <div class="slide1"></div>
    <div class="slide1"></div>
    <div class="slide1"></div>
    <div class="slide1"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="full-width">
  <div class="box2">
    <div class="slide">
      <p> I want this div above than the red div</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CSS position property:

```css
.full-width
{
  width:100%;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  position:relative;
}
.box-width
{
  position:relative;
  max-width:500px;
  margin:0 auto;
  height:150px;
  background:yellow;
}
.box2
{
  max-width:400px;
  margin:-30px auto 0 auto;
  height:150px;
  background:red;
   position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
.slide
{
  max-width:200px;
  height:60px;
  background:orange;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
.slide1{
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="full-width">
    <div class="box-width">
      <div class="slide1"></div>
      <div class="slide1"></div>
      <div class="slide1"></div>
      <div class="slide1"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="full-width">
    <div class="box2">
      <div class="slide"><p> I want this div above than the red div</p ></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.slide {
    max-width: 200px;
    margin: -25px auto 0 auto;
    height: 60px;
    background: orange;
    position: relative;
    top: -50px;
}
```