# Why p element at the top would create margin to parent element?

Tags: html, css

So I have a div with a p inside at the top of current document. And I'm setting `margin-top` onto the `<p>` expecting there could be a margin between the div and p elememt. What makes me misunderstanding is the result that the `margin-top` is shown between the body and the parent div. See the example.

But if I set the `div.container` with a 1px border, the `margin-top` could be brought back between the p element and its parent div.

What's more, if the `div.container` is set as flex display instead of default block, the `margin-top` could work intuitively as well.

How come? And can I do anything about it?

```css
html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: grey;
}

.container {
  background-color: red;
  display: block; /* flex could also make it work */
  margin: 0;
  /* The border setting would bring back the margin-top on p */
  /* border: 1px solid black; */
}

.paragraph {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<p class="paragraph"> sadf </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: grey;
}

.container {
  background-color: red;
  display: block; /* flex could also make it work */
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* The border setting would bring back the margin-top on p */
  /* border: 1px solid black; */
}

.paragraph {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<p class="paragraph"> sadf </p>
</div>
```

It is all about vertical margin collapse.

the quickest solution is adding overflow: hidden; for parent element.

You learn more about vertical margin collapse here

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing

As you can in edited snippet it is fixed.

Comment: I've learned margin collapse before, but why the margin-top of children element could have affect on parent container makes me still unable to understand relation to the design of margin collapse. Could you provide some more detailed advices?

Comment: @千木郷 This post might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19718634/how-to-disable-margin-collapsing