# Why is the margin not fitting into the div?

Tags: html, css, margin

My button margin isn't fitting into my div. Here's the relevant HTML and CSS.

```css
.card {
  justify-content: flex-start;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 20%);
  margin: 8px;
}
.card {
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  padding: 0px 8px;
  float: left;
}
.button {
  border: none;
  padding: 8px;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
}
.button:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}
.title {
  color: grey;
}
.container {
  padding: 0px 16px;
}
.card > img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
    <div class="ccard">
        <div class="card">
            <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1115280588322295808/N1mHLfHy_400x400.png" alt="Jane">
            <div class="container">
                <h2>Jane Doe</h2>
                <p class="title">CEO & Founder</p>
                <p>Jane has had 9 years of experience in the tech industry and knows it like the back of her hand. She's very warm and welcoming towards new customers.</p>
                <p>janedoe@cabbagedude.com</p>
                <p>
                    <button class="button">Contact</button>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

It has always worked for me before, but it doesn't work now. I also haven't changed anything, except by adding the class ccard around card.

Here's what it looks like for me.
[image]

Comment: You've got `.ccard` in your css but `class="card"` in your html.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable margin-collapsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19718634/how-to-disable-margin-collapsing)

Comment: pistevw, sorry i forgot to add something

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `box-sizing: border-box;` to all relevant elements in order to *include* borders and paddings (I suppose you mean those, since you don't have any margin on the button) in the given `width`, otherwise they are *added*  to the width, which causes overflow if the width is 100%.

Comment: I meant margins on the p

Comment: In this case @CBroe is correct about pointing you to margin-collapsing. If you add a 1px padding-bottom to the parent element (`.container`), the margin-bottom on the `p` tag will not collapse anymore.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I needed, sorry about that