# How to avoid margin collapse of two elements inside their respective parents?

Tags: css

How to prevent the margins of both inner divs from collapsing?

[Here's](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-2cuw4x) the Stackblitz

```css
.block {
    margin: 8px 0;
    height: 20px;
    width: 40px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="block"></div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: here can be useful - https://stackoverflow.com/q/19718634/10749726

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grid layout mode doesn't collapse margins:

```css
body {
  display: grid;
}

.block {
  margin: 8px 0;
  height: 20px;
  width: 40px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```