# Unexpected scroll bars with calculated height accounting for margin

Tags: css

I have the following CSS and HTML

```css
body {
  margin:0px
 }

.outer {
  height: 100vh;
}

.inner {
  height: calc(100vh - 20px);
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
  </div>
</div>
```

This results in scroll bars.

If I remove the 'outer' class, everything works as expected - no scroll bars.

Obviously, the outer class is redundant, however, I want to know why the scroll bars appear

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is because browsers define a default margin for the `body`.

Your `outer` starts lower and to the right by about 10px (the default `margin`), and then extends its size equal to the size of the viewport by creating the scroll bars.

When the default `margin` is reset, the scroll bars disappear.

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0px;
 }

.outer {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: green;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100vw - 40px);
  height: calc(100vh - 40px);
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
  </div>
</div>
```

### UPDATE

*In my first answer I had copied your code including an error (`margin 20px` on the `.inner` class) that did not allow me to see this further "problem", however the first answer remains valid, even if partial.*

This second problem in my opinion is due to the "margin collapse". Here is a paragraph (of [this MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing)) that I believe is your case:

> These rules apply even to margins that are zero, so the margin of a
> descendant ends up outside its parent (according to the rules above)
> whether or not the parent's margin is zero.

If you inspect with the browser developer tools (maybe with colors it is easier than with both white boxes) you will realize that the margin of `.inner` comes out of his parent `.outer`.

You can find the solution in the MDN guide, in my case I set `position: absolute` to `.inner` class, but you can find the same answers here: [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19719427/4031083)

And last thing `margin: 20px` applies 40px of margin per height (20px top and 20px bottom) and 40px width, so your `calc` should be `height: calc(100vh - 40px);`.

**Code updated above**

Comment: I already had 0 margins on the body!
I've updated my question