# How/why does an inner element have its margins extend into a containing element?

Tags: html, css

Some very simple html:

```html
<header class="my-header">
    <div class="no-margins">
        <p>Nicolay Copy</p>
    </div>
</header>
```

And css:

```css
.my-header {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 1;
}

.no-margins {
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

Here's the F12 computed for the containing `<div>`

[image]

And here's the F12 computed for the contained `<p>`.

[image]

Shouldn't the margins for `<p>` be inside the `<div>`? Obviously they aren't, but why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs:

> If there is no border, padding, inline part, block formatting context
> created, or clearance to separate the `margin-top` of a block from the
> `margin-top` of one or more of its descendant blocks; or no border,
> padding, inline content, `height`, or `min-height` to separate the
> `margin-bottom` of a block from the `margin-bottom` of one or more of its
> descendant blocks, then those margins collapse. The collapsed margin
> ends up outside the parent.
>
> – [Mastering margin collapsing | MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing)

Since there is nothing between `.no-margins` and `p`, its first and last child, their `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` collapse. `.no-margin`'s margins are all 0, so their `margin-top` and `margin-bottom`, as a whole, ultimately take `p`'s as the value.

For solutions, see [How to disable margin-collapsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19718634).

Comment: Every time I think I've seen css at it's screwiest, then I learn something stranger. Anyways, thank you - very well written answer.