# How to remove extra space taken by html tag?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZRG5.png)

Space taken by outside of box is the space taken by index tag and that I want remove. I am developing this in ReactJS

[Code Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBDYL.png)

[Styled Components 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHUtW.png)

[Styled Components 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dvfha.png)

Comment: Check the html or body tags padding and margin. You can make those 0 by using css. Also provide some code sample to re-create the issue. Also you can use jsfiddle or equivalent to give working sample.

Comment: I have already tried by giving margin & padding 0 but it won't work.

Comment: Provide some sample code to re-create. Otherwise no one can help.

Comment: I have added images of code please checkout.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Your HTML structure makes little sense to begin with - headline elements can not be nested into each other.

Comment: The outer `h1` headline _is_ likely the cause of your problem here though - the effect is called _collapsing margins_, https://stackoverflow.com/q/19718634/1427878

Comment: How can I fix this problem of collapsing margins, I followed the link that you have sent but not able to understand what to do? @CBroe

Comment: There is _multiple_ ways explained in that other discussion already. And if you got nothing but "not able to", then I don't know how to help you any further ... I could only repeat the explanations given.

Comment: Copying the code is easier than taking a screenshot of the code, for you and us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the extra space taken by the element you need to do some changes in the CSS file

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

The above code will set the margin and padding for all the element to 0 by default also the border-box will help you to design properly.