# Margin not applied to parent but body

Tags: css

I have `div` `container-sm` with padding. But its child- `h1`'s margin not applied to `container-sm`'s edge, instead it applies between header, as below.

```css
    header {
        background: lightblue;
    }
    .container-sm {
        width: 70%;
        padding: 0 15px;
        background: #ddd;        
    }

    .text-xl {
        font-size: 2rem;
        margin: 40px 0 20px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>I'm header</header>
    <section>
        <div class="container-sm">
            <h1 class="text-xl">Topic heading</h1>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: issue]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable margin-collapsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19718634/how-to-disable-margin-collapsing)

Comment: It mentioned appling padding to the parent. I already have padding in the div.

Comment: Try giving your `.container-sm` `padding-top: 0.05px;`

Comment: @HaoWu re-opended for answering.