Background image not moving

I'm working on a project on react js using javascript, html & css.
background image isn't starting from the top and i can't figure out why. and it is not the same for other pages.

I was expecting it to work like the image here.
here is the code:
 import ill from '../../assets/ill.png'
    import './Homepage.scss'
    import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

    const Homepage = () => {
       return (
            <> <div style={{  position: 'relative', /* Ensure proper positioning */
            height: '100vh', /* Full viewport height */
            background: 'linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(29, 236, 197, 0.7), rgba(91, 14, 214, 0.7) 100%)', /* Gradient background */}}>
                <div id="message" >
                    <p class="first">Making it easy <span>to find a PC.</span></p>
                    <p class="second">We are happy to help you find a PC!</p>
                    <button id="con-btn" class="btn"><Link to="/info" className='nav-link'>Continue as guest</Link></button>

                    <img id="ill" src={ill} alt="illustration" />
            
                </div>
                </div>  
            </>
        )
    }

    export default Homepage;

Css:
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inter');

body {
    margin: 0;
    /* Remove default margin */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;

}

#ill {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 150px;
    width: 400px;
    max-width: 500px;
    max-height: 500px;
    opacity: 100;
    position: relative;
    top: -200px;
}

.btn {
    background-color: #3A75AC;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 8px 15px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;

}

#message {
    margin-top: 200px;
    margin-left: 160px;
}

.first {
    font-family: Inter;
    font-size: 50px;
    color: #4D4D4D;
    font-weight: bold;
}

span {
    color: #3A75AC;
}

.second {
    font-family: Inter;
    color: #717171;
}


#input {
    margin-top: 150px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    margin-left: 150px;

}

#input select {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    width: 220px;
    height: 50px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

#head {
    font-weight: bold;
}



Can't tell for certain, but I'm guessing you have a classic "collapsing margins" problem here. https://stackoverflow.com/q/19718634/1427878

Due to the margin-top: 200px of #message
Margins can cause the collapse of the parent element's height, and this issue can be resolved by utilizing the Block Formatting Context (BFC). One way to establish a BFC for the parent element is to set the overflow property to either hidden or auto.
Add div as #message parant and set height: auto; overflow: auto;
