# How do I leave a margin on the top and bottom of this rectangle

Tags: html, css

I have created an outer div element and I am trying to make a simple rectangle inside it. Now, the horizontal positioning of the first side is spot on. However, for the vertical positioning, I want to have a margin of 10px between the top, bottom of the lenght1 div and the outer div. 
Below is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
*{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;

 }
 body{
    margin:10px 0px;
 }
div.outer{
    height:400px;
    width: 500px;
    margin:100px auto;
    margin-top: 130px;
    background-color:red;
 }
 div.length1{
    height:380px;
    width:30px;
    margin:10px 470px 10px 0px;
    background-color:blue;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="outer">
      <div class="length1"></div>
      <div class="breadth1"></div>
      <div class="length2"></div>
      <div class="breadth2"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable margin-collapsing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19718634/how-to-disable-margin-collapsing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Margins on the inner div's collapse, hence doesn't get pushed as expected.

It is very well explained here:

- [Mastering margin collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing)
- [How to disable margin-collapsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19718634/how-to-disable-margin-collapsing)
- [How do I uncollapse a margin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828804/how-do-i-uncollapse-a-margin)

One way is to give the parent `overflow: auto`

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
body{
  margin:10px 0;
}
div.outer{
  height:180px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color:red;
  overflow: auto;
}
div.length1{
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
  width:30px;
  margin: 10px 0 10px 10px;
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="length1"></div>
  <div class="breadth1"></div>
  <div class="length2"></div>
  <div class="breadth2"></div>
</div>
```

---

Another way is to use `padding` on the parent instead of `margin` on the children

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
body{
  margin:10px 0;
}
div.outer{
  height:180px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color:red;
  padding: 10px;
}
div.length1{
  height: 100%;
  width:30px;
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="length1"></div>
  <div class="breadth1"></div>
  <div class="length2"></div>
  <div class="breadth2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. @LGSon
However, can the same results be achieved without padding? I mean can't I add margins to the inner div itself?

Comment: @SwastikMohapatra Updated my answer

Comment: @LGSon Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @SwastikMohapatra You're welcome, and if my answer solved your question, please accept it as well

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
position:absolute;
```

in the length1 style.

like:

```
.length1{
    height:380px;
    width:30px;
    margin:10px 470px 10px 0px;
    background-color:blue;
    position:absolute;
 }
```

You can also use .length1 instead of div.length1 :)

and I would remove:

```
*{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;

 }
 body{
    margin:10px 0px;
 }
```

Comment: No worries, any time :)