# Why is '::after' pseudo-selector over the image and not under it?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I have this container with some text and an image inside it as last element, I am trying to set an `::after` to my container, however it is being shown over the image and not as the last element of the container:

I understand that I can't set a pseudo-selector to an `<img/>`, but here I am setting `::after` to the container and I don't get why it isn't working properly.

Why is this happening and how could I make `::after` actually the last element of `testDiv`?

P.S. I can't set the container or any parent element with `position: relative`, since I need `::after` to have the same width as the screen and not just to fit inside the container and I don't have any element with the same width as the screen.

P.S. The `margin-left:100px` is just to make it easier to be seen in the snippet, therefore it doesn't matter to my purpose.

```css
.testDiv > div::after {
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  content: "";
  background-color: red;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.testDiv > div {
  margin-left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="testDiv">
    <div>
      <h1>TEST</h1>
      <h2>TEST</h2>
      <img src="https://www.acmetek.com/wp-content/uploads/rapidssl-logo.png" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: position:relative to the div and add bottom:0 to pseudo element

Comment: It doesn't solve my problem, since I need the `::after` to have the width of the screen and not only of the container.

Comment: position:relative on testDiv then or use position:fixed .. make your question more clear so I can grab the correct duplicate

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I can see, neither existing answer actually address the question of why the line is over, not under the image. The reason can be found in [CSS 2.2 Section 10.6.4. Absolutely positioned, non-replaced elements](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/#abs-non-replaced-height) where it says if:

> top and bottom are auto and height is not auto, then set top to the static position, set auto values for margin-top and margin-bottom to 0, and solve for bottom

and

> the static position for top is the distance from the top edge of the containing block to the top margin edge of a hypothetical box that would have been the first box of the element if its specified position value had been static and its specified float had been none and its specified clear had been none.

Which means that the top of the absolute positioned box will be the top of where the box would have been had not been `position:absolute`.

Since both the img and the ::after pseudo element without `position:absolute` are `display:inline` they would have lined up alongside one another. The pseudo element taken out of the flow and stretched horizontally to meet the `left:0;right:0` requirements.

What this means is that you can move the red line to below the img just by making the ::after pseudo element `display:block`.

This is quite an interesting effect given that we normally think of `position:absolute` blockifying the box anyway, but this only happens *after* the static position calculation.

Another solution, perhaps a little more intuitive, is to make the img element `display:block`.

```css
.testDiv > div::after {
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  content: "";
  background-color: red;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display:block;
}

.testDiv > div {
  margin-left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="testDiv">
    <div>
      <h1>TEST</h1>
      <h2>TEST</h2>
      <img src="https://www.acmetek.com/wp-content/uploads/rapidssl-logo.png" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: exactly .. that was my duplicate(https://stackoverflow.com/q/54774549/8620333) to the question but it got reopened .. let's hope the OP will get convinced with your answer

Comment: Thank you very much, @Alohci. Your answer is very clear.

Comment: @Temani Afif , I apologize, now that I read this answer I can see that the post you pointed out makes sense, but only now. When we are learning we need simple explanations, as this one. The other post answers the question, but it's all very technical, if I had this level of understanding I could have figure it out by myself and I wouldn't have asked. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: as a side note, since the vertical alignment is baseline, the pseudo element would have been located next to the image but at the bottom of the line so I would imagine that the static position will pick the top of the linebox

Comment: @TemaniAfif you're right, but at the time the question looked different. Meanwhile I've closed as dupe

Comment: @TemaniAfif - The point that the static position seems to based on it having `vertical-align:top` bothers me a bit. While it's clear that it's the only vertical alignment that wouldn't be problematic by either affecting the vertical position of all the other elements on the line, or else results in an indeterminate static position depending on what happens to the line box layout when the box is removed from the flow, I don't know of anything in the CSS specs that calls for it. Have you come across any spec requirement that justifies it?

Comment: not really, I accepted the fact that using the sentence *.. user agents are free to make a guess at its probable position.* in [the Spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html) means that we don't have precise rules to define the static position and browsers are free to take the *easiest* one

Answer (score 2):

You can still use `position:relative` but have your element overflow from both sides:

```css
.testDiv>div::after {
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  content: "";
  background-color: red;
  left: -100vw; /* big value here */
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: 100vw 0 0 red; /* big value here too*/
}

.testDiv>div {
  margin-left: 100px; /* we have a margin */
  width: 200px; /* and a width too */
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="testDiv">
  <div>
    <h1>TEST</h1>
    <h2>TEST</h2>
    <img src="https://www.acmetek.com/wp-content/uploads/rapidssl-logo.png" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="testDiv">
  <div>
    <h1>Another one </h1>
    <h2>TEST</h2>
    <img src="https://www.acmetek.com/wp-content/uploads/rapidssl-logo.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Given your comment

> It doesn't solve my problem, since I need the ::after to have the width of the screen and not only of the container

You need to set `position:relative` to  `.testDiv`  parent and also add `bottom:0` and `width:100%` to the  pseudo element

```css
.testDiv {
  position: relative
}

.testDiv>div {
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.testDiv>div::after {
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  content: "";
  background-color: red;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class="testDiv">
  <div>
    <h1>TEST</h1>
    <h2>TEST</h2>
    <img src="https://www.acmetek.com/wp-content/uploads/rapidssl-logo.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

#### UPDATE - based on your comment

you will need either set `bottom: (any value)(any unit you need)` or `top: (any value)(any unit you need)`

```css
.testDiv>div::after {
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  content: "";
  background-color: red;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 50px;
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class="testDiv">
  <div>
    <h1>TEST</h1>
    <h2>TEST</h2>
    <img src="https://www.acmetek.com/wp-content/uploads/rapidssl-logo.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It would work if `testDiv` had the same width as the screen, but that's not the case. This is just an example. I really need to set `::after` based on the screen and not on any parent element. I edited my post to make it a bit clearer.

Comment: @Berg_Durden see updated answer

Comment: It works. It's better than moving my margins. So, it seems that the only way is moving something. Just for educational purposes, do you know why `::after` is not positioned after `<img/>`? As I said in the question, I understand why I can't put a pseudo-selector to an img tag, but I believed that in this case it would work, since I am using a `div`.

Comment: it is all about the `position` attributes, you were missing `top`(or) `bottom`, and by default the values to them are `auto` making the line in the middle

Comment: I thought about that, but what is bugging me is that when I have only text inside the div it works properly and `::after` is positioned as the last element, but when I have specifically an image it doesn't happen.