# Why does padding change the height of the child div with border-box set?

Tags: html, css, css-position, padding

I have the following piece of html

```html
<div style="position: relative; box-sizing: border-box; width: 400px; height: 400px; padding-top: 20px;">
  <div style="position: absolute; height: 80%; background-color: aqua; width: 100%;"></div>
  <div style="height: 80%; background-color: black; width: 100%;"></div>
</div>
```

I have a parent div with a height of 400px and two child divs where each child has a height of 80%.

- The first div has position absolute, this one has the correct height (400 * 0.8) = 320px .
- The second div size is 304px which is smaller.

After some trial and error I found that the `padding-top: 20px` on the parent div causes this.

Could someone explain to me why this happens and how to make the divs the same size?

This seems to happen in all major browsers.

Comment: When you give position:absolute your eelement  is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is created for the element in the page layout. It is positioned relative to its closest positioned ancestor so it is unaffected by padding but the other div affected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#containing-block-details):

> The position and **size of an element's box(es)** are sometimes calculated relative to a certain rectangle, called **the containing block** of the element. The containing block of an element is defined as follows:
>
> ..
>
> 4. If the element **has 'position: absolute',** the containing block is established by the nearest ancestor with a 'position' of 'absolute', 'relative' or 'fixed', in the following way:
>
>    1. In the case that the ancestor is an inline element, the containing block is the bounding box around the padding boxes of the first and the last inline boxes generated for that element. In CSS 2.1, if the inline element is split across multiple lines, the containing block is undefined.
>    2. Otherwise, the containing block is formed by **the padding edge of the ancestor.**

So the `position:absolute` element will use `400px` that include **the padding**

> For other elements, if the element's position is 'relative' or 'static', the containing block is formed **by the content edge of the nearest block container ancestor box.**

The other one will use the content-box which is `400px - 20px` so you won't have the same height

```
400*0.8 = 320 [positionned element]
(400 - 20)*0.8 = 304 [non-positionned element]
```

This is somehow logical since padding is a way to create space so it will get removed from the calculation when considering non-positionned elements. This logic is different for positionned element.

An example to illustrate:

```css
.box {
  border:2px solid;
  padding:20px;
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  position:relative;
}

.box > div:last-child {
   height:100%;
   width:100%;
   background:red;
}

.box > div:first-child {
   position:absolute;
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   background:rgba(0,255,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

---

When it comes to position it's a different story. Below a related question to understand how the elements is positionned if you don't set top/left/right/bottom and you will see that padding will play a role here:

[Why aren't my absolutely/fixed-positioned elements located where I expect?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54774549/8620333)

---

If you don't set `box-sizing:border-box`, the logic will remain the same but the values will change.

From the specification related to the default value `content-box`

> This is the behavior of width and height as specified by CSS2.1. The specified width and height (and respective min/max properties) **apply to the width and height respectively of the content box** of the element. The padding and border of the element are laid out and drawn outside the specified width and height.

The calculation will become

```
(400 + 20)*0.8 = 336  [positionned element]
400*0.8 = 320 [non-positionned element]
```

---

If you want them to have the same size you need to define the height differently for the absolute element:

```css
.box {
  height: calc((100% - 20px)*0.8);
}
/* OR */
.box {
  top:20px;
  bottom: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div style="position: relative; box-sizing: border-box; width: 400px; height: 400px; padding-top: 20px;">
  <div class="box" style="position: absolute; background-color: aqua; width: 100%;"></div>
  <div style="height: 80%; background-color: black; width: 100%;"></div>
</div>
```

Or don't use `position:absolute`

```css
.box {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 80%; /* the height here */
}

.box > * {
  grid-area: 1/1; /* make both elements on top of each other */
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div style="background-color: black;"></div>
  <div style="background-color: aqua;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the amazing answer!