# Why when i put float:right on <div> it goes down?

Tags: html, css

I want #cart to go to the right top of the page. When I add float, it goes down. Why? I'm putting there codes and images **with** and then **without** the float.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

#fl {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  color: transparent;
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 60px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 60px;
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  opacity: 0.8;
  border-left: 5px solid black;
  font-family: 'Nanum Gothic', sans-serif;
}

#log {
  height: 60px;
  margin-top: 2px;
}

#container {
  width: 70%;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: rgba(111, 250, 171, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black;
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

#cart {
  font-size: 30px;
  float: right;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="cart">CART</div>
<div id="fl">
  <h1><span>BUY EXCLUSIVE ONDRIWATER TODAY</span></h1>
</div>
<div id="container">
  <div class="greensale">
    <span class="more">400ml</span> for just <span class="more">200$</span>
  </div>
  <div id="log">
    <img src="logo.png" height="60" width="60" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note: the `<img>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make the element floating the next one (`id="fl"`) will become the first in-flow element and its top margin will collapse with the top margin of its the container (`body`). it's like you increased the top margin of the container by 
  `margin-top: 100px;` and since the floating element is placed considering this one the element will jump to its new position.

To avoid this, [you need to avoid margin to collapse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828804/how-do-i-uncollapse-a-margin):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  padding-top:1px;
}

#fl {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  color: transparent;
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 60px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 60px;
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  opacity: 0.8;
  border-left: 5px solid black;
  font-family: 'Nanum Gothic', sans-serif;
}

#log {
  height: 60px;
  margin-top: 2px;
}

#container {
  width: 70%;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: rgba(111, 250, 171, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black;
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

#cart {
  font-size: 30px;
  float: right;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="cart">CART</div>
<div id="fl">
  <h1><span>BUY EXCLUSIVE ONDRIWATER TODAY</span></h1>
</div>
<div id="container">
  <div class="greensale">
    <span class="more">400ml</span> for just <span class="more">200$</span>
  </div>
 
</div>
```

Adding background to the body will make you better see the issue. Comment/uncomment the floating property to see what is happening:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  background:red;
}
html {
 background:#fff;
}

#fl {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  color: transparent;
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 60px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 60px;
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  opacity: 0.8;
  border-left: 5px solid black;
  font-family: 'Nanum Gothic', sans-serif;
}

#log {
  height: 60px;
  margin-top: 2px;
}

#container {
  width: 70%;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: rgba(111, 250, 171, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black;
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

#cart {
  font-size: 30px;
  float: right;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="cart">CART</div>
<div id="fl">
  <h1><span>BUY EXCLUSIVE ONDRIWATER TODAY</span></h1>
</div>
<div id="container">
  <div class="greensale">
    <span class="more">400ml</span> for just <span class="more">200$</span>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

in your code #cart is top and right your page! 
so, you could use absolute position like:

```
#cart {
  font-size: 30px;
  right: 0;
  top:0;
  height: 40px;
  position:absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of `float: right` do `text-align: right`. The float-style will align the `#cart`element with `#fl`