# Resizing an element using $.width() becomes larger instead of narrower

Tags: jquery, css

```js
$('#btnw').on('click', function() {
  $('#story').width(90 + 'px');
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#story {
  width: 100px;
  background: lightgreen;
  padding-right: 45px;
}

.title {
  background: gold;
  margin: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='story'>
  <div class='title'>
    lorem
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<button id='btnw'>CLICK</button>
```

First of all - where are top and bottom margins on `title`?

And why `box-sizing` is lost after click on `button`?

Result - `story` becomes larger instead of narrower for 10px;

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are using the method incorrectly, use `css()` instead

See the jQuery [**docs**](http://api.jquery.com/width/) for more info

> The difference between `.css(width)` and `.width()` is that the latter
>   returns a unit-less pixel value (for example, 400) while the former
>   returns a value with units intact (for example, 400px). The `.width()`
>   method is recommended when an element's width needs to be used in a
>   mathematical calculation

```js
$('#btnw').on('click', function() {
  $('#story').css('width', '90px');
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#story {
  width: 100px;
  background: lightgreen;
  padding-right: 45px;
}

.title {
  background: gold;
  margin: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='story'>
  <div class='title'>
    lorem
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<button id='btnw'>CLICK</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't agree with the accepted answer. Explaning the difference bettwen the **getters** isn't accurate and don't asnwer the question. Here you need to understand why setting the width using each method is different. You need the explanation of the **setters**.

First, we need to keep in mind two different concepts: `width` and `innerWidth` (there is also the `outerWidth` but we don't need it here).

[image]

When using `width()` you are setting the element width (without padding/border) to the value specified. In other words, the `width()` property will set the CSS property `width` to a value that will make the content width equal to the needed value. It will not simply set the value of the CSS property `width`.

In your case you have a padding of `45px` and you want the content width to be `90px` so the total width is `135px` and since we are using `box-sizing:border-box` the `width` property need to be set to `135px` and not `90px` in order to achieve a content width equal to `90px`

```js
$('#btnw').on('click', function() {
  $('#story').width(90+'px');
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#story {
  width: 100px;
  background: lightgreen;
  padding-right: 45px;
}

.title {
  background: gold;
  margin: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='story'>
  <div class='title'>
    lorem
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<button id='btnw'>CLICK</button>
```

If you check the dev tools you will clearly see this:

[image]

Now if you remove `box-sizing:border-box` you will have the content width and the value of `width` both equal to `90px`.

```js
$('#btnw').on('click', function() {
  $('#story').width(90+'px');
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#story {
  width: 100px;
  background: lightgreen;
  padding-right: 45px;
}

.title {
  background: gold;
  margin: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='story'>
  <div class='title'>
    lorem
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<button id='btnw'>CLICK</button>
```

In this case, width doesn't include padding thus jQuery will simply set the `width` property to the value specified.

[image]

---

When using `innerWidth()` , jQuery will set the `width` property in a way to make  width+padding equal to the value specified.

```js
$('#btnw').on('click', function() {
  $('#story').innerWidth(90+'px');
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#story {
  width: 100px;
  background: lightgreen;
  padding-right: 45px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.title {
  background: gold;
  margin: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='story'>
  <div class='title'>
    lorem
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<button id='btnw'>CLICK</button>
```

This is somehow the result you are looking for because you was thinking about the overall width (padding + width) and not only the content width.

Here is the result without `box-sizing`. Again a different value set to the `width` property.

```js
$('#btnw').on('click', function() {
  $('#story').innerWidth(90+'px');
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#story {
  width: 100px;
  background: lightgreen;
  padding-right: 45px;
}

.title {
  background: gold;
  margin: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='story'>
  <div class='title'>
    lorem
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<button id='btnw'>CLICK</button>
```

---

Now, when using `.css()` there is no complex calculation. jQuery will simply set the `width` property to value specified and then the result will depend on the other CSS properties.

So using `width()`/`innerWidth()` will oblige jQuery to calculate and set a specific value (sometimes different from the one specified) to the `width` property in order to have the adequate result BUT using `.css()` will simply set the `width` property with the value specified with no calculation.

---

Concerning the margin you are facing a [margin-collasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828804/how-do-i-uncollapse-a-margin) issue that you can easily fix by setting `overflow:hidden` to the parent container `#story`.