# How can I get some element width inside setInterval correctly without delaying?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to increase some progress bar using `setInterval`. When I test, it's working fine.

```js
var progressBar = $('.progress-bar');

var count = 0;

var interval = setInterval(function () {
    var width = progressBar.width();

    console.log(width++);

    progressBar.width(width);

    count++;

    if (count === 101) {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, 50);
```

```css
.progress-bar {
  width: 0px;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #00f;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="progress-bar"></div>
```

Since I nest it into dropdown, I'm getting trouble with the time to repeat every action:

```js
var increase = function (progressBar, ms) {
    var count = 0;

    var interval = setInterval(function () {
        var width = progressBar.width();

        console.log(width++);

        progressBar.width(width);

        count++;

        if (count === 21) {
          clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, ms);
}

$('.dropdown').on('shown.bs.dropdown', function () {
    var progressBar = $(this).find('.progress-bar');
    
    increase(progressBar, +progressBar.data('ms'));
});
```

```css
.progress-bar {
  width: 0px;
  height: 4px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="dropdown d-inline-block">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Progress bar with 100ms
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" >
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
        <div class="progress-bar" data-ms="100"></div>    
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown d-inline-block">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Progress bar with 300ms
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
        <div class="progress-bar" data-ms="300"></div>    
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I open the dropdown, the progress bar width will be increased. But there is something wrong when I try different values to repeat the action.

In the example, if I set the value to `100` or lower, I'll get the progress bar width *wrongly*. The default width value is `0`, after increasing (by adding `1`), why it's `0.15625` and then `0.3125`...?

Another try, if I set the value to `300` or higher, I get the width *correctly* *(0, 1, 2...)*

Anyone knows why?

Comment: related for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53791182/8620333

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use css width property instead od jQuery [`width()`](https://api.jquery.com/width/) method since [`width()`](https://api.jquery.com/width/) may return unreliable data.

```js
var increase = function (progressBar, ms) {
    var count = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
        var width = parseInt(progressBar[0].style.width) || 0;
        console.log(width++);
        progressBar[0].style.width = `${width}px`;
        count++;
        if (count === 21) {
          clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, ms);
}

$('.dropdown').on('shown.bs.dropdown', function () {
    var progressBar = $(this).find('.progress-bar');
    
    increase(progressBar, +progressBar.data('ms'));
});
```

```css
.progress-bar {
  width: 0px;
  height: 4px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="dropdown d-inline-block">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Progress bar with 100ms
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
      <div class="progress-bar" data-ms="100"></div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown d-inline-block">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Progress bar with 300ms
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
      <div class="progress-bar" data-ms="300"></div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Taken from [docs](https://api.jquery.com/width/):

> Note that .width() will always return the content width, regardless of the value of the CSS box-sizing property. As of jQuery 1.8, this may require retrieving the CSS width plus box-sizing property and then subtracting any potential border and padding on each element when the element has box-sizing: border-box. To avoid this penalty, use .css( "width" ) rather than .width().

Comment: Perfect. My fault when testing without reading the docs. Many thanks!