# What is the means of "margin collapse"?

Tags: css, xhtml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [For what reason margin collapse rules were introduced in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1438114/for-what-reason-margin-collapse-rules-were-introduced-in-css)

What is the means of "margin collapse"?

Comment: Collapsing margins is part of the CSS Spec. What do you mean by "problem".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a problem, it's a design decision. It means: when adjacent elements have margins that "touch", the two margins are collapsed into the same space. So for example:

```
_____
| A |    Element A has 20-px bottom margin
|___|

        <-- space between elements is 20, not 40
_____
| B |    Element B has 20-px top margin
|___|
```

The margins are "collapsed" together. The CSS specification requires browsers to behave this way by design. It is actually a Good Thing and helpful, once you understand when and how it is happening.

Comment: Why is it a Good Thing? I think that was what the original question was getting at..

Comment: @Magne the reason is scalability of design. The true power of CSS starts to show when we use it to write general-purpose rules about how certain *kinds* of elements should display, without knowing precisely how those elements will be arranged on a particular page. The purpose of margin is to create a **gutter** between elements. In design specifications it is common to say a gutter should be precisely (x) pixels - so collapsing ensures that properly-designed margins on unpredictable element arrangements will never exceed the desired gutter size.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the generalizability aspect. I can see that's a good thing. I'm just annoyed by the fact that one still has to know precisely how some elements are arranged on a particular page, since the collapsing of margins is dependent on the nearby elements (i.e. inline-blocks vs blocks).

Comment: @Magne if margin collapsing is a problem for you, that generally means you are expecting adjacent elements' margin to "push each other apart", which means you are using margin incorrectly. That should be accomplished with padding.