# CSS: space <li> so they are evenly distributed vertically in a <div> of fixed height

Tags: html, css

I have a `<div>` with a fixed height of 400px in which to display product bullet points using `<li>`. If I have 8 `<li>`, they fit pretty well in the space given. If I have only 4 `<li>`, there is a lot of extra white space below the `<li>`. How can I use CSS to make the `<li>` space evenly within the `<div>` instead of leaving any extra space in the bottom of the `<div>`?

I found this question:
[Evenly distributing or spacing list items vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14189931/evenly-distributing-or-spacing-list-items-vertically)
which seems to be pretty similar but there is no chosen answer and none of the answers really solve the problem. Ideally this would be just CSS not a javascript solution.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) See [about Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: @JohnConde Yes fair question.. sorry I wasn't clear, I did try the solutions in the question I linked to (one involved javascript and one some CSS tags that I wasn't familiar with). Neither worked like I was hoping and I really don't want to use javascript for this anyways. Aside from that I pretty much did a lot of tinkering with the CSS in the chrome developer tools to try to get things to fit nicely but I'm coming here with the question because I'm hoping there is some CSS for this purpose that I'm just not aware of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you don't have `li`'s as direct children of a `div`, this would not be valid HTML.

To evenly distribute `li`'s inside a `ul`, you could set the `ul` to `display: table` and the `li`'s to `display: table-row`:

```
ul {
    height: 300px;
    display: table;
}
li {
    display: table-row;
}
li:before {
    content:'•';
    float: left;
    width: 20px;
    font-size: 1.8em;
    line-height: 0.75em;
}
```

Here's a <kbd>[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/TzWzt/5/)</kbd>

If you have a `div` wrapping the `ul`, and you want the `li`'s to be evenly spaced vertically inside this `div`, all you'd need to change is setting the fixed `height` on the `div` instead, and setting the `ul`'s `height` to `100%`.

**Edit**

I realised the solution didn't play well in any version of IE, this updated version fixes that by rendering the bullet point inside the pseudo element, and it then set the `font-size`, `line-height` and `width` on the pseudo element to get it to look good and line things up, [it works in IE8+ and all other browsers](http://caniuse.com/css-gencontent).

Comment: He needs bullet points. if not, he could have used table instead

Comment: @KhanhTo - Hmm, true, I didn't think of that, that's an easy fix though, I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try this now. Yes I do have the <li> in a <ul>, just mentioned the <div> because that is the part with the fixed height limit.

Comment: Works perfectly.. thanks! I'll mark this as the answer. Just wondering how do the tags you put in li:before fix the bullet points? (why content:' '; ?) It works, but I don't understand it.. ?

Comment: the `li:before` renders a pseudo element inside the `li` container, it needs some content set (it won't be rendered without content set, it could be `''`, but I believe `' '` makes sure it works in all browsers) and then it is set to `display: list-item;` to ensure a bullet point is rendered. `float: left;` makes it sit nicely at the left inside the container and ensures the pseudo element doesn't force a line break.

Comment: What you said is not correct. This is just a trick to make it work, the list is displayed as a table. You just put a "." before each item to make it look like a list item, but actually, it's displayed as a table row.

Comment: @KhanhTo - If you checked the **Edit** part of my answer, you can see that I modified the solution after I added that last comment, as it worked fine everywhere except in IE. I should probably remove the comment. Besides that, I'm not putting a `.` character inside the pseudo element but a `•` character, which is an actual bullet point. Also, I don't think using a trick to make it work is a bad thing? It's about the desired result, not about how you arrive at the desired result. As long as it works it should be fine.