# Box Model - Why does a margin for header screw with sticky footer

Tags: html, footer, sticky-footer, css

I am trying to use the following sticky footer solution from http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -4em;
}
.footer, .push {
    height: 4em;
}
h1 {
    margin-top:1em;  
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="layout.css" ... />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <h1>This header screws with sticky footer</h1>
            <p>Your website content here.</p>
            <div class="push"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <p>Copyright (c) 2008</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

However, as the above snippet demonstrates adding a margin to the <h1> tag  results in an undesired scrollbar.

From my basic understanding, the margin should affect only the size of the <h1> tag, which should not affect the size/position of the wrapper (unless there is no space - but clearly there is plenty of space).

**EDIT:** I am not trying to find a solution, I want to understand what happens. It appears that the margin does not push the <h1> tag down relative to the parent container, but instead it pushes the parent container down together with the <h1> tag. Is this correct, and if yes, why? It seems fairly counter-intuitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to manipulate margins/paddings property its always save to add `display:inline-block` property instead of using inline elements. Add it to your `h1` tag and your problem will be fixed.

Here is a post with some of explanation about this issue 
[Inline elements and padding](http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/inline/)

**Edit:** I have an explanation for you.

In CSS we have something like **"collapsing margins"**. This is how W3C define it:

> In this specification, the expression collapsing margins means that adjoining margins (no non-empty content, padding, or border areas, or clearance separate them) of two or more boxes (which may be next to one another or nested) combine to form a single margin.

Margins are adjoining only when:

> - both belong to in-flow block-level boxes that participate in the same block formatting context
> - no line boxes, no clearance, no padding and no border separate them (Note that certain zero-height line boxes are ignored for this purpose.)
> - both belong to vertically-adjacent box edges, i.e. form one of the following pairs:
>
>   - top margin of a box and top margin of its first in-flow child
>       bottom margin of box and top margin of its next in-flow following sibling
>   - bottom margin of a last in-flow child and bottom margin of its parent if the parent has 'auto' computed height
>   - top and bottom margins of a box that does not establish a new block formatting context and that has zero computed 'min-height', zero or 'auto' computed 'height', and no in-flow children

If you want to read more about it, here you have some useful links:

- [W3C.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins)
- [Understand CSS Margins Collapsing](http://960development.com/understand-css-margins-collapsing/) (clear explanation + examples)

To sum this up, there are many different ways to solve this issue. For example adding `display:inline-block` , `float:left` or even `border:1px black` properties to your wrapper element or `h1` tag will fix the "problem". Of course it's not a real problem, in some cases collapsing margins is really useful.

Comment: Thank you, this was useful information in general, but does not really help with my problem/question. I would like to understand why the margin on the <h1> tag affects the .wrapper container.

Comment: I have updated my answser. There is explanation now. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks - technically I have already found the answer myself, but you put slightly more effort into your answer, so I will accept it instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `overflow:auto;` or `overflow:hidden;` to you wrapper div. This might be a better solution if you want to keep your `h1` as a block element.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not looking for solutions, I am trying to understand why it happens.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that my problems is caused by [collapsed margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins), the rules for which have been introduced to yield consistent spacing between elements that all have margins. Without the collapsing margin rules, margins would in some cases be applied twice.

This is explained more comprehensively in [another stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1438114/for-what-reason-margin-collapse-rules-were-introduced-in-css).